# Spring Boot throwing autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

It all started after i included the below in springboots pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.Beta2</version>
</dependency>
```

i am using hibernate validators like @NotNull , then started getting the below errors "datatype source not found", i did follow some of the other stackoverflow q&a where they asked me to include h2 and that added to the mess.

I have my application.properties file where i have configured it for using mongo ?

is there a way to fix it  ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, all you are trying to do is validation.
And for only validation, you do not need to include `hibernate-core` dependencies.

replace your dependency with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

version `5.1.3.Final` is latest stable release.

Comment: no luck.. issue still continues. we are integrating a non spring boot project with a spring boot project. This  may be root cause for this issue